How to return all records based on type of course?
The Course model has few properties, one of them is
public string CourseType { get; set; } = null!;

For listing all courses my service (CourseService) contains
public List<Course> GetAllCourses()
{
    var Allcourses = _context.Courses.ToList();
    return Allcourses;
}

And the controller
//Get all Courses
[HttpGet("GetAllCourses")]
public IActionResult GetAllCourses()
{
    var allcourses = _courseservice.GetAllCourses();
    return Ok(allcourses);
}

How can I create a [HttpGet("GetElectives")] that only returns Courses where the CourseType is “Electives”?

Have you ever worked with collections in C# before? Like var numbers = new []{1, 3, 6}; var odds = numbers.Where(n => n % 2 != 0); it's the same idea. return Ok(allcourses.Where.(course => course.Type == "Electives"));

First set the HttpMethodAttribute get to [HttpGet("GetElectives/{courseType}")] , this Attribute, makes your endpoint to able take parameter from url.
Second you must develop your service to return by CourseType.
Like this :
public List<Course> GetCoursesByCourseType(string type)
{
    var AllCourseType = _context.Courses.Where(a=>a.CourseType == type).ToList();
    return AllCourseType ;
}

